# Can I skip a level in content drilldown in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a rails web app where many of the url pathss are of the form:

```
/people/12345678/category
```

...where the `12345678` is the user's id. What I would like to do is not match the second level, or use a wildcard or something so I can easily look at the stats for where *everybody* in the third level (the category bit).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a filter for /people/\d+/category using the Regex Match and get the totals for that.

Another idea is to setup a filter to standardize these urls removing the user id so you get cleaner reports. You can create a new profile and setup and advanced filter to transform the url removing the id. That will give you a cleaner report.

Make sure to keep an unfiltered profile around in case you screw up data using filters. This way you make sure you don't lose any data.

Comment: This seems the sort of thing. I already use filters to check internal or external (to the company) visits separately but this is a bit more complex.  So would I have to set up a filter for each category? Or is there a way of writing the filter in such a way that in removes the id whilst keeping all the categories?